# groovy map populate with default element

Tags: groovy

Is there more Groovish way of adding an element to map of lists and initialize default list if not exists?

Or in other words what would be a Groovish way to code the below:

```
def mylist = [1,2,3,4]
def mymap = [:]

for (num in mylist){
  if (num % 2 == 0){
    pairity = "even"
  } else {
    pairity = "odd"
  }


  if (mymap.containsKey(pairity)){
                println("Adding to Even")
                mymap[pairity].add(num)
  } 
  else {
                println("adding to Odd")
                mymap[pairity] = [num]
  }
}
print(mymap.toString())

// adding to Odd
// adding to Odd
// Adding to Even
// Adding to Even
// [odd:[1, 3], even:[2, 4]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [withDefault](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#withDefault(groovy.lang.Closure)) on a map to have automatically generate a value for a missing key on access.

```
[1,2,3,4].inject([:].withDefault{[]}){ m, i -> m[ i%2==0 ? 'odd' : 'even' ] << i; m }
// => [even:[1, 3], odd:[2, 4]]
```

Comment: thanks @cfrick! I guess this is what I've been looking for. 
Could you elaborate on the other parts? Afraid I'm a bit lost between the lines of the one-liner :)

Comment: `[:].withDefault{[]}` gives you map, that populate missing keys with a value of an empty list.  `withDefault` takes a closure, and will use the result of that closure for the value.  The rest is just an example how to solve your problem (yet `groupBy` is better for your problem)

Comment: thanks! I'll I agree that group is better for the problem, but the problem is just an example to assist with the question about populate with default. Hence I'll go ahead and accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply `groupby`:

```
def mymap = mylist.groupBy { it % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd' }
```

That is effectively using the closure to partition the list on the condition.

Comment: Thanks! it's very informative, I've explained why other answer is accepted in comment on that answer.